# my isPrime's range is not working, it gives just the first number

Tags: python, range

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.6

def isPrime(n):


if n == 1:
    print("1 is a special")
    return False


for x in range(2, n):
    if n % x == 0:
        print("{} is equal to {} * {}".format(n, x, n // x))
        return False
    else:
        print(n, " is a prime number")
        return True


for n in range(1, 21):
    isPrime(n)

isPrime(2)
isPrime(21)
isPrime(25)
```

and the result it gives to me is:

```
1 is a special
3  is a prime number
4 is equal to 2 * 2
5  is a prime number
6 is equal to 2 * 3
7  is a prime number
8 is equal to 2 * 4
9  is a prime number
10 is equal to 2 * 5
11  is a prime number
12 is equal to 2 * 6
13  is a prime number
14 is equal to 2 * 7
15  is a prime number
16 is equal to 2 * 8
17  is a prime number
18 is equal to 2 * 9
19  is a prime number
20 is equal to 2 * 10

21  is a prime number
25  is a prime number
```

there is no result of (2),
and also this is result of 'even-odd' numbers, not 'isPrime' , because in the code '***for x in range(2, n)***' , it has calculated only with number 2 for x

what is wrong in my code ?

Comment: Please fix your indentation. It's hard to read as is.

Comment: returning true, or false; will result in you to break out of the function.

Comment: 1.) in `range(2, n)`, for n = 2 , will give you `[]` empty list.
2.) you are using `return True` for for first value of x i.e. for 2. if your number is divisible by 2 it return False and for odd number True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't return `True` form the first iteration. Not being divisible by 2 does not make it prime:

```
for x in range(2, n):  # it would be enough to loop to sqrt(n)
    if n % x == 0:
        # you know it is NOT prime after first divisor found
        return False 
# you only know it IS prime after you tried all possible divisors
return True
```

Comment: your explanation was great, i totally understood it

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
def isPrime(n):
    if n == 1: 
        print("1 is a special")
        return False
    for x in range(2, n):
        if n % x == 0:
            print("{} is equal to {} * {}".format(n, x, n // x))
            return False
    print(n, " is a prime number")
    return True

for n in range(1, 21):
    isPrime(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in range(2, n):
    if n % x == 0:
        print("{} is equal to {} * {}".format(n, x, n // x))
        return False
else:
    print(n, " is a prime number")
    return True
```

Watch the indentation: else is now is in aligned with for (not with if), and it should solve your problem. Else means that the x got iterated over n, so n%x was never 0 => you got a prime

Comment: also for x in range(2 ,n/2) or even for x in range(2, math.sqrt(n)) should be enough

Comment: yes, exactly ... your explanation is detailed, i understood what was my wrong ... thanks, done.